# ExecutorCompletionService missing invokeAll interface

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

So reading the javadoc of [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html), looks like it uses threadpoolexecutor that has methods like `invokeAll()`, however, the `ExecutorCompletionService` only provides submit() method, therefore not allowing us to call `invokeAll` and triggering all tasks at once if tasks are submitted through the `ExecutorCompletionService`.

Should not it support `invokeAll()` so that I can prepare a list of tasks and call something like

ExecutorCompletionService.invokeAll(listOfTasks);

instead of calling

```
ExecutorCompletionService.submit(task);
```

in a for loop?

Comment: That's not how `ExecutorCompletionService` works. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An `ExecutorCompletionService` is a `CompletionService`, not an `ExecutorService`. The whole point of a `CompletionService` is to provide a mechanism to check for completed tasks through polling.

[`invokeAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) blocks until all submitted tasks are completed.

These are opposing features.